# Huge difference in KMO statistic based on type of correlation (Pearson vs Polychoric)

Tags: correlation, pca, factor-analysis, polychoric

I am analyzing an engagement survey filled out by teenagers in a school following a randomized trial in which they were assigned to either of two experimental conditions (lessons). The questionnaire aims to determine which of the two conditions engaged them better and which one they generally liked better. I am trying to do some PCA/Factor Analysis, and since the items in the survey are measured on a 4-point Likert-scale, I thought I would use polychoric correlation as a basis of my correlation matrix to be used by PCA/PAF. When I calculate a KMO statistic in R using a regular Pearson correlation matrix, KMO is aeround .75, which should be appropriate for FA as far as I know. However, if I use polychoric correlation, KMO is only .25 which is way too low to even bother with FA. Is there anything in the calculation of the polychoric correlation coefficient that would account for a difference of this magnitude?

Comment: I was seraching for the exact same thing. How did you calculate the KMO based on polychoric correlation, is that implemented in a R Package?

Comment: Hey! I realized in the end that I was using a different kmo function for one of the matrices, that caused the issue. The KMO function from the psych package can be run on polychoric correlation matrices as well, and (at least for me) gave almost the same result as the Pearson's correlation matrix. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped me a lot

Comment: Could you please explain (as an edit to the post) KMO?